# how to efficiently debug processess created by fork()

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I want to know whether there is any way to debug (using gdb) both child and parent processes simultaneously. I know the command used to change processes to child one. But that is not the solution I am looking for, as this method only has control of either the child or the parent. I am looking for simultaneous execution steps of both child and parent.

For instance, say the child is executing the a'th step in program b, while the parent is executing the c'th step in program d.

It seems that stepping through the processes of both parent and child is necessary. Is there any way to do this, and if so, how might I go about doing it?

Comment: This isn't really an answer, but have you considered a GUI debugger like ddd?  Last time I used it, it allowed me to switch between all process in a multi-process app. involve ddd is a front end to gdb, it stands to reason that this is also possible in gdb, however, I would gather it's pretty involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to know whether there is any way to debug(using gdb) both child and parent processes simultaneously.

Yes, [there is](http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/MultiProcess). Documentation [here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Inferiors-and-Programs.html) and [here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Forks.html#Forks). If you are on Linux, you'll want to

```
(gdb) set detach-on-fork off
```

Answer (score 3):

Regarding ctt's comment, it's not hard to do with gdb, as I've just found out. I found [this resource](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~maclean/csc209/ddd-gdb-children.html), which works for both ddd and gdb:

> **Using gdb/ddd to debug child processes**
>
> If you have tried to debug a child process using ddd, you may have
>   noticed that ddd steps into the parent (and not the child) after the
>   call to fork(). It is possible to debug the child as well, but it
>   requires a special procedure. Since the child is a seperate process,
>   it will require a second debugger window, and we will make use of
>   gdb's ability to "attach" to a process which is already running.
>
> **Before you start, you must do the following:**
>
> Make sure your call to fork() assigns a value to some variable so you
>   can read it easily, e.g. `pid = fork()`.
>
> Make sure you place a sleep() statement in the child as the first line
>   of code after the fork(), e.g. `sleep(60)` [make the sleep() long
>   enough for step 4 below ...]. The sleep() statement can be removed once
>   debugging is complete. [You only need to do this if you need to attach to the child process right away.]
>
> Compile your program with the "-g" option set, e.g. `gcc myProg.c -o myProg -g`
>
> **Now you are ready to start:**
>
> Start 2 copies of ddd [or gdb] in the background, like `ddd myProg & ddd myProg &` [or for gdb, start gdb as normal (e.g. `gdb myProg`) in two separate terminals]. It is important that the two copies being running concurrently.
>
> Pick (arbitrarily) one window to be the "parent" and set a breakpoint
>   after the call to fork() (but not in any code the child will be
>   executing ... that is, set the breakpoint somewhere in the parent's
>   code ... if you set the breakpoint in the child's code, DDD will kill
>   the child as soon as it is created!).
>
> Run the parent to the breakpoint. Note the value returned by fork(),
>   i.e. the process ID of the child.
>
> In the "child" window, type "attach " in the gdb console window
>   where  is the child's process ID. Note: the gdb console is found
>   at the bottom of the ddd window; this is where you can type commands
>   directly to gdb.
>
> Set a breakpoint in the child after the sleep() statement, and click
>   on "cont" (in the popup "Command Tool" window) to allow the child to
>   continue execution to the breakpoint.

You will also need to type `c` or `continue` in the child gdb after you attach. Use `print pid` to see the value of `pid`.

If you have a process that kicks off a different process, then start the child gdb passing in the name of the child process. Ex. if program `a` kicks off program `b`, you want one terminal with `gdb a` (parent gdb) and one with `gdb b` (child gdb). In this case, you `run` from the `gdb a` terminal (it is no longer arbitrary).

This answer was more helpful to me because I'm using an older version of gdb, for which `set detach-on-fork off` wasn't working as I expected. This way you also don't have to suspend the process(es) you're not currently debugging, which may be required for some purposes.